# VBA Changing Value of Multiple Cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have a row of cells that depending on which option button I have selected, will display a certain range of values. It isn't based on any equations or any logic. I need to display a specific set of values across multiple cells.

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
If OptionButton1.Value = True Then Range("B3","AF3").Value = 

End Sub
```

How would I indicate multiple values across cells in this case? Would I put all my values into some sort of an array first and then just feed the array into the `.Value`? Thanks!

Comment: yes, that's one way to go about it.

Comment: @sous2817 and it would know to parse the values in the array into each cell? Would I seperate the values with commas?

Comment: no, you'd have to loop through the array and put whatever array index you want in the appropriate cell.

Answer (score 3):

The method I ended up using is as follows.

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3","AF3").Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B3","AF3").Value
```

Answer (score 2):

There is probably a more elegant way, but here is one way to go about it:

```
Sub test()

Dim strArray(0 To 2)    As String
Dim rng                 As Range
Dim cell                As Range
Dim counter             As Long

Set rng = Range("A3,B7,G5")
counter = 0

strArray(0) = "Value1"
strArray(1) = "Value2"
strArray(2) = "Value3"

For Each cell In rng
    cell.Value = strArray(counter)
    counter = counter + 1
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: @DeeWBee Sure, is the range you want to use a continuous or discontinuous range?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by that?